# config update without login onto server

Tags: sitefinity

In sitefinity can I edit web config setting ? I dont see anything in the `Administration/Settings/Advanced` and would love to be able to edit the setting without login onto the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings you edit in Administration / Settings / Advanced are stored in configuration files in App_Data / Sitefinity / Configuration folder and/or in the database table sf_xml_config_items.

One way to edit the web.config is to download it first from Administration / File Manager, then edit it locally and then upload it back.